# Rename JSON object inside a list using MapNeat

Tags: java, json, kotlin

How can I rename a field using mapneat, which is inside a list object like this

```
{
    "detail" : [
        {
            "name" : "huda"
        },
        {
            "name" : "syahnaz"
        }
    ]
}
```

into this

```
{
    "detil" : [
        {
            "nama" : "huda"
        },
        {
            "nama" : "syahnaz"
        }
    ]
}
```

I try to transform it like this but doesn't work

```
fun test(jsonRequest: String, setup: String): MapNeat {

    val transform = json(MapNeatSource.fromJson(jsonRequest)){
        "detil[*].nama"*="detail[*].name"
    }
    return transform;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally answered by the MapNeat author

here is the answer

```
    val source = "
{
    "detail" : [
        {
            "name" : "huda"
        },
        {
            "name" : "syahnaz"
        }
    ]
    }
"

fun main() {

    var value = json(fromJson(source)) {
         "detail" *= "$.detail"
        val detail = getObjectMap().get("detail") as List<Object>

        "detil" /= detail.map {
            json(fromObject(it)) {
                "nama" *= "$.name"
            }
        }.toList()

        - "detail"
       
    }.getPrettyString()

    print(value)
}
```

The output

```
{
  "detil" : [ {
    "nama" : "huda"
  }, {
    "nama" : "syahnaz"
  } ]
}
```

The main idea is to:

- Select "detail" from source to target: "detail" *= "$.detail"
- After this line, it becomes accessible inside getObjectMap() which keeps the internal representation of the target as Map<String,Object>. You cast the result to List` (because it's an array).
- Then you iterate over detail, and apply a new transformation for each element.
- You remove "detail" at the end because you don't need it anymore.

Original link you can see at the Mapneat github discussions

[Mapneat discussion](https://github.com/nomemory/mapneat/discussions/27)